# Entity Framework DataContexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm wrestling with a design and trying to figure out the best way of approaching it.

We have many tables, and in a current LinqToSql implementation, our DBML is many megs in size, very unwieldy. I want to avoid recreating this situation if I can. We decide our connection string on a per user basis, so it got very difficult to make separate dbmls for different groups of tables.

I'm set on using Entity Framework, and although we don't need the Code First elements, I'm liking the lightweight code without all the generation and we don't need the visual mapping so I was thinking of generating the code files for all the tables and then adding them into a DataContext as DbSets.

This got me thinking about best practice here, and I wanted to ask the question;

Is it wise to create a DataContext for every group of tables you want to use. I.e. I'm going to have a module, it will be responsible for gathering data from 5 tables, it doesn't need every single table in the database, just 5. Do I create a DbContext that includes these 5 tables. If I need more in the future I can add them in, but it's lightweight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you may have a separate context for each grouping of tables, if your model is that large, or your domains that disparate, you may want to look into adding a layer of abstraction.  By this, I mean having a single context that encompasses your whole model, then adding something along the lines of the [repository pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).  [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/16/using-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-with-entity-framework-4-0.aspx) is a decent write-up on accomplishing this with EF.

By doing this, would you be essentially accomplishing two goals: abstracting out your data tier, thus freeing up implementation concerns; and, allowing your developers to work with just the entities they need, possibly grouped by [aggregate root](http://richarddingwall.name/2009/10/13/life-inside-an-aggregate-root-part-1/).

One thing I would like to make clear though.  I am not necessarily suggesting that you go with a specific end-to-end architecture (i.e. DDD). What I am trying to do here is suggest a few patterns that will give you the flexibility to allow you to make mistakes (fail gracefully) while still making progress with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do this. You just add tables to the edmx model just as in Linq2SQL so by just adding the 5 tables you need you'll save on having any overhead for entity tracking for the other untracked tables. Entity Framework nicely adds 2-way Navigation Properties which Linq2SQL doesn't have too. I'd recommend using EF instead of Linq2SQL.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently bad about a large DBML model, the performance impact should be negligible in EF.

On the other hand in my opinion reducing complexity also applies to Entity Framework - if your code only needs 5 tables from the database by all means create a separate context that only has the entities for those 5 tables. By factoring out completely independent tables into separate contexts you are expressing this separation in clear way - there are no dependencies from these tables to other tables in your database, and no dependencies from the code to unrelated entities - if that is the case I think (and there might be other opinions) this is the way to go.

However keep in mind that if you need some of those tables in another context you would have to put the corresponding entities into that context as well - it can get hard to understand that the same tables are present in multiple context or even have cross-dependencies between contexts. That should be avoided since it adds complexity.

Comment: Thank-you, this helps me a lot to know I'm not wasting time and energy